# How to find the upper bound of a binomial coefficient by using binomial theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, approximation

I have a task to find a upper bound of the binomial coefficient for all $r \leq \frac{n}{2}$. I've already obtained by using such relation:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{r}}$$
Which gives the upper bound $\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{n}{k} \leq \binom{n}{r}\frac{n-r+1}{n-2*r+1}$.

But for getting more precise approximation I was asked to use formula for fixed constant $t \in (0, 1)$ and $t^{-r}(1+t)^n$, where $t=\frac{n}{n-r}$.

I've transformed that statement $$t^{-r}(1+t)^n = t^{-r}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}t^k=t^{-r}\left(\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{k}t^k + \sum_{k=r+1}^n\binom{n}{k}t^k\right)=\\=\left(\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{k}t^{k-r} + \sum_{k=r+1}^n\binom{n}{k}t^{k-r}\right)$$
Because we need to approximate only result for $r$ I decided to through away the right sum $\sum_{k=r+1}^n\binom{n}{k}t^{k-r}$.

Now I have only $$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{k}t^{k-r}$$ which I should approximate by using the idea that $0 < t < 1$, but I have no idea how to do that.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying bound... the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{n}{k}$? or just $\binom{n}{k}$? or $\binom{n}{k}$ as related to $\binom{n}{r}$?  It is unclear how $k$ and $r$ are related in your first bound (other than $k\leq r$?).  Could you please try to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I need to obtain the upper bound of $\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{k}$ where $r \leq \frac{n}{2}$. And this approximation should be done by using binomial theorem with the fixed constat $t \in (0,1)$

Comment: Finally there should be something stronger than this bound $\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{n}{k}\leq \left(\frac{ne}{r}\right)^r$

Comment: Why do you bound $\binom{n}{k}\leq \binom{n}{r}\frac{n-r+1}{n-2r+1}$ when $\binom{n}{k}\leq \binom{n}{r}$ and $\frac{n-r+1}{n-2r+1}\geq 1$?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course there should be $\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n}{k} \leq \binom{n}{r}\frac{n-r+1}{n-2r+1}$